# Cloud function hides nested logs

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I have a Cloud Function in Python that prints a dictionary that has dictionaries and arrays in it.

The cloud functions omits the nested dictionaries and arrays and just logs "...". How can I see the full log?

[image]

Comment: Go to Cloud Logging?

Comment: If you are using Logs Explore in Cloud Logging then you should have a small arrow to the left of that log entry allowing you to expand and collapse nested log fields. Do you see that toggle? And is your data displayed when you toggle it? https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-explorer-interface#query-results

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere will try - terrible UX though spreading log functionality ‍♂️

ianyoung there is no arrow for print commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happen because I am using cloud functions v2. I had to check the logs on the logs explorer